# jQuery Ajax not returning success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code that goes to form.php instead of pulling the echoed php into a #success div on my main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    data = $(form).serialize();
    $('#form').submit(function() {   
        $.ajax({
        url: '../wp-content/themes/MC/form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#success').html('').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
                <div id="form">
                <br>
                <form action="http://www.mcfilmmakers.com/wp-content/themes/MC/form.php" method="post">
                    Name / Nom:<input type="text" name="fullname" /><br />
                    E-mail / Courriel:<input type="text" name="email" /><br />                          Your Daily URL / Votre URL Quotidien:<input type="text" name="link" /><br />
                    Voting Instructions / Instructions de Vote:<textarea name="instr" style="width: 450px; height: 100px;"/></textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="success">
            </div>
```

The form.php does recieve the post information because it is echoing the input. For some reason though, it's just not being inserted into #success.

Comment: did you miss the document ready?

Comment: Is your page reloading? Don't you need to `event.preventDefault()` on `#form` submit?

Comment: @Book of Zeus I am not forgetting document ready. It's there, I just didn't paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: '../wp-content/themes/MC/form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#success').html(result);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

When submitting your form, by default it will post the form the the `action` attribute of the form. You want to prevent that post from happening, and instead do it with ajax. So [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) will prevent that.

Also no need to chain `.html('')` because it sets the entire content. See http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: _Give a man a fish, he eats for a day..._ -- An answer explaining the provided solution is often more valuable than the solution itself (regardless of how accurate it is).

Comment: @BradChristie I added a small explanation.

Comment: @rfausak: Thank you. I'd also go in to the change you did with `.html()` and why the OP's version is not working. -- I hope my previous answer cam across the correct way; I was just hinting at giving a user reasoning helps both them and future visitors with the same possible problem. It also avoids future "here's my code, fix it" sort of questions later one.

Comment: @Brad Christie I agree. Explanations are always better. Explanations however are so hard to come by in plain english with jQuery however.

Comment: And after I go through the effort of answering and explaining, I don't get the accepted answer. Sigh..

Comment: @rfausak I removed id="form" from <div> and attached it t <form> a suggested below and plugged in your changes. The oddest thing happens: In chrome, the php echo does appear in the #success but the variables don't make it through (I just see Name: Email: Link: Instructions: instead of Name: Paul Email: test@test.com, etc) and in Firefox I am still being sent to form.php where the output is as it should be but obviously, I shouldn't be sent to form.php.

Comment: I would remove `action=".."` from your `<form>`. Also the `data` variable contains nothing, that's why the variables are not appearing.

Comment: @rfausak but the data variable contains var data = $(form).serialize(); and like I said, in firefox form.php IS outputting those variables.
I have removed action = but the code still won't returnt he variables in #success in chrome and in firefox I am sent to form.php where the variables are being returned.

Comment: @Jonathan it sounds like you are having a problem unrelated to this question. Perhaps you should open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

your code:

```
$('#form').submit(function()

#form points to `div id="form"`
```

You register onsubmit event to div.
try adding `id=form` like this:

```
<form action="http://www.mcfilmmakers.com/wp-content/themes/MC/form.php" method="post" id="form">
```

and delete `id="form"` from div.

Comment: Unless they intend on styling the div. The better solution would probably just alter the selector to `#form form`. But +1 for catching the selector error.