# JQuery Ajax stops working after adding .submit(function() { }

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The original issue was that JQuery Ajax won't call succuess after hitting the C# method. By looking at a similar issue here: [jQuery Ajax not returning success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549782/jquery-ajax-not-returning-success) i see that the solution was to add:

```
$(parentForm).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();`
```

However, after doing this, the Ajax code doesn't seem to execute. I do hit the JS function though, but it stops before it executes Ajax code.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
@{
    const string formId = "parentForm";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditChannel", "Channel", FormMethod.Post, new { id = formId }))
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("EditChannelForm", Model);
        <br /><br />

    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="editChannel('@Model.ChannelViewModel.ID', @formId)" />

    }
```

I submit this form in the JS code (when the button above is clicked) that looks like this:

```
function editChannel(channelId, parentForm) {
  $(parentForm).submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          url: "/Channel/EditChannel/",
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,
          data: {
              id: channelId,
              updatedModel: parentForm
          },
          success: function(msg) {
              alert("Msg: " + msg);
              if (msg === "ChangeOfSensitiveData") {
                  showAlertOnChangeOfSensitiveData('sensitivDataMsgDiv');
              } else {
                  alert("Else");
              }
          },
          error: function(msg) {
              alert("error");
          }
      });
  });
}
```

I do hit the JS function, but the ajax never executes, and therefore not calling the C# method. If I only do like this:

```
function editChannel(channelId, parentForm) {
    $(parentForm).submit() 
    ...
```

Then the AJAX code executes and hits the C# method, but never hits the success function.

The C# looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditChannel(int id, ChannelAndLocationViewModel updatedModel)
{
    updatedModel.LocationItemViewModels = GetLocationItems();            

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ChannelModel channel = null;
        using (var context = new MaaneGrisContext())
        {
            var oldUnit = context.Channels.Where(c => c.ID == id).Select(c => c.Unit).SingleOrDefault();
            var newUnit = updatedModel.ChannelViewModel.Unit;

            if (oldUnit != null && !oldUnit.Equals(newUnit))
            {
                return Content("ChangeOfSensitiveData");
            }
            ...
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: No no errors at all. Looking at the network when submitting, it deosn't even commeti a post

Comment: You are passing form id to the function so your submit should be `$('#'+parentForm).submit(...`

Comment: @ShaunakD I am not sure that is the issue, since it works when doing `$(parentForm).submit() `. I tried your suggestion however, and it didn't make any difference :-)

Comment: That code works because you have not added `event.preventDefault()` and original form action(added by Html.beginform occurs.

Comment: What are you actually trying do do here? Your code just passes the initial value of `ChannelViewModel.ID` that exists when you first render the view and the string "parentForm" to the `editChannel()` function. `$(parentForm).submit()` wont do anything, and even if you did pass a valid form to the method what would be the point of calling `.submit()` and then immediately cancelling it.

Comment: Of course I am not gonna cancel it once it works, right now I am just trying to get a hole through. I want the user to be promted when he is trying to edit a channel by editing some sensitiv column. I need to use JQuery Ajax because I need to call back to the user telling him that he is trying to edit sensitive data, so that he can confirm

Comment: So what I really want to do, is submit the form from the JQuery Ajax (and return success), instead of using MVC's `<input type="submit" ... />`.

Comment: Then you code makes no sense. You need to serialize the form, not just send a string which is what `updatedModel: parentForm` is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code is passing the models `ChannelViewModel.ID` value and a string with the value `"parentForm"` to the `editChannel()` method, which then passes that string to the controllers `EditChannel()` method. The parameter `updatedModel` is a complex object of type `ChannelAndLocationViewModel` which cannot be bound to a string so binding fails and the value of `updatedModel` will always be null.

Remove the `onclick` attribute and change the button to

```
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save" />
```

Then modify the script to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("EditChannel", "Channel")';
var channelID = '@Model.ChannelViewModel.ID
$('#save').click(function() {
  // serialize the form and add the additional parameter
  var data = $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ id: channelID });
  $.post(url, data, function(msg) {
    alert("Msg: " + msg);
    ....
  });
});
```

Alternatively, include `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ChannelViewModel.ID)` in the view and just use `var data = $('form').serialize()`  The value for `ChannelViewModel.ID` will be included in the post and the `int id` parameter is not required in the controller method (it will be bound in the `updatedModel` parameter).